# How to redirect all photos to the https protocol using htaccess

Tags: .htaccess

I have photos in various directories, these are jpg, jpeg, png, gif files - on the website they are linked as http://my.site.pl/*/photo.jpg I want to redirect them to https://my.site.pl /*/photo.jpg - how to do it with htaccess

I have done such a redirect:

```
RewriteCond     %{SERVER_PORT} ^80$
RewriteRule     ^(.*)$ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.
RewriteRule .* https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
```

but not working for photos.

Comment: Why not simply redirect _all_ traffic to https??

Comment: Also, please dont add unrelated tags

Comment: Do you have an SSL certificate on your domain?

Comment: yes i have certificate - working for main page but not working for photos

Comment: Comment out this line `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.` and test your image URL in a new browser